# Is there any app that records notes with synchronized Audio?

Tags: audio, synchronization, recording, notes

Is there any application that it records audio and you take notes. After recording you can play the audio that was recorded when a specific text was written. There are apps that does this for other OS like this one:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audionote-notepad-voice-recorder/id369820957?mt=8

The ideal would be that after recording, I could select a text and it could play the audio that was recorded when that specific text was written.

Comment: Note that OS/X falls under Unix+Linux. What OS are you interested in?

Comment: A Linux OS more precisely in a Debian environment. The best i could do myself was to from the script data as times from the Stéphane Chazelas answer, create an HTML5 with the notes and at the end of each text a media player with the sound starting at the specific time

Comment: See also pyvnc2swf that creates a flash video of the screen or a region of the screen or a window. You can mix recorded audio to the video.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, you could do:

```
{
  your-prefered-sound-recording-application > sound.ogg &
  script -c 'vi file' -tdump.times dump
  kill "$!"
}
```

And to replay:

```
{
  your-prefered-sound-playing-application < sound.ogg &
  scriptreplay dump.times dump
}
```

(here assuming the `script`/`scriptreplay` from `util-linux`).

It doesn't have to be `vi`, any terminal application (even `sleep infinity`) will do.

Comment: First of all, many thanks for the fast reply. It's not exactly this, but with this maybe I can do something. The ideal would be that after recording, I could select a text and it could play the audio that was recorded when that specific text was written. With this solution, I need to see the whole audio check what was the audio when I wrote the text. Maybe if i could forward the replay it would be an OK solution